How can I attach an addEventListener to an input field using the submit event?
I am making a simple tip calculator and first of all I am trying to save the value of the bill amount which the user can type into the input field (this input field has a type number attribute). There aren't any button to submit the value so I'd like to use the submit event for the addeventlistener instead of the click event. Inside the addeventlistener I am preventing the default behavior of the event and then I am trying the save the amount as a variable but the console is empty all the time.
Here is the HTML code:
<div class="form_bill">
    <h2>Bill</h2>
    <div class="input_icons">
      <i class="fa fa-usd icon"></i>
      <input type="number" class="form_input bill_input" placeholder="0"/>
    </div>
</div>

Here is my JS code:
const billInput = document.querySelector('.bill_input');

billInput.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const billAmount = billInput.value;

    console.log(billAmount);
});

I tried to change the input tag to form tag, I tried to change the type number to type text, I tried the click event, no success. I'd like to save the input value as a variable so after that I could work with that value.

Read up on the docs on the SubmitEvent. It says that the submit event is emitted from the <form> element. In any case, why do you want to use the submit event when you don't have a button to submit with? What's the goal here?

Are you trying to submit actually something to some backend service or just "save"... and by save - what do you mean exactly? Save where?

The Submit event is triggered by <form> element not <input> element, you can listen for change event so anytime the value of input changes your event is triggered and you can save the most recent value
billInput.addEventListener('change', () => {
    const billAmount = billInput.value;
    console.log(billAmount);
});


Why "change" instead of "input" eventName?

we can use the input event as well, but that will fire on every keystroke, considering OP initially wanted a submit event I thought the change will be more appropriate since we only want to save the final value as bill amount

There are different event that are fired when the value of an input changes. The input event will fire when the value has changed. Read more about the input event.
In general be careful not to have too many variables. In this case you would like to have billAmount as a variable for the value of the input -- but the input already have that value, so why another variable -- it is more code to keep track of? In this example you can always refer to the value by document.forms.bill.numberinput.value and just e.target.value inside the event callback function.


document.forms.bill.numberinput.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
  const billAmount = e.target.value;

  console.log(billAmount);
});
<form name="bill">
  <h2>Bill</h2>
  <div class="input_icons">
    <i class="fa fa-usd icon"></i>
    <input type="number" name="numberinput" class="form_input bill_input" placeholder="0" />
  </div>
</form>



